# phpmyadmin .htpasswd file missing in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, .htpasswd

I have installed mysql-server 5.5 and phpmyadmin. It was working before but currently I am having Internal Server error for phpmyadmin.

In apache server error log following message is showing.

```
[Wed Jan 21 02:38:26.501839 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 12948] (2)No such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:42201] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
```

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file in that directory that has a line with `AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd`?

Comment: Have you tried creating this file and re-running?

Comment: What should i put in .htpasswd file? any suggestion or reference would be convenient.

Comment: @Ding Currently .htaccess file is not present in /etc/phpmyadmin directory

Comment: Did you edit any of the configuration files manually? As far as I can tell (and recall), this error message is not consistent with the way the Ubuntu package is installed. Run `grep -R "phpmyadmin/.htpasswd" /etc/apache2/*` (assuming you use Apache) and see which file is looking for the .htpasswd file.

Comment: A .htaccess file was added to secure phpmyadmin but password was not set. After running `sudo htpasswd -c /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd username` the problem has been fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

To secure phpmyadmin a .htaccess was added containing following configuration

```html
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

But didn't created the password. The password can be created using following command.

```html
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd username
```

Answer (score 0):

if /etc/phpmyadmin/.httpasswd exists then
`chmod +r /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd`
else try to purge phpmyadmin package and install it again